# Activity gets re-created during the transition to a new one

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

In the App I'm developing I've got 2 Activities, **ActA** and **ActB**.

ActA is the first one to be displayed.

We can say **ActA** works like a SplashScreen.

Inside **ActA** i retrive some data which i need in **ActB** for performing some tasks.

When this data get retrived i can call an Intent which perform the switch to **ActB**.

Here's the problem: 
**ActB** extends **ActA** becouse it needs **ActA** retrived data to perform his tasks.

Probably becouse of that, in the moment **ActB** gets called, **ActA** method "OnCreate" gets called to.

This create a loop becouse **ActA** starts retriving other data and calls again ActB. So my app Crash.

**How do i forbid ActA to start a second time?**

Comment: You should use an interface to pass on the data, or pass the data through intent, instead of doing it.

Comment: `Here's the problem: ActB extends ActA becouse it needs ActA retrived data to perform his tasks.` Well, indeed it is the problem. You should be passing that parameter to `ActB` and not extend `ActA`.

Comment: Can you post your Activities?

Comment: It's better to use intent to send data from ActA to ActB so once the ActB gets started ActA will not be called.

Comment: The problem is that the data i need to send is a BLE device and all his characteristiches end services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to exchange data between Activity you can do this.
Create a base activity like this:

```
    class BaseActivity extends Activity{
      String data;
    }

    Now class ActA extends BaseActivity{
    //you can put value to data directly
    data="ABCD";
    }

    class ActB extends BaseActivity{
    //Here you can access the data string directly
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your retrieved data from ActA to ActB via an intent, like this

```
Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), ActB.class);
i.putExtra("String1", "foo");
i.putExtra("Integer1", "1337");
startActivity(i);
```

and then in your ActB you reviece the data like this:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
String foo = i.getStringExtra("String1");
Integer leet = i.getStringExtra("Integer1");
```

If you want to pass a custom object, please reffer to [How to send an object from one Android Activity to another using Intents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents)

Comment: I'll try, the problem is that the data i need to send are not simple integers or String but a BLE device with is services and characterisiches

Comment: You forget to mention that OP's approach is completely wrong. This is half an answer at most

Comment: @L.Gangemi like i said: if you want to pass an bigger object, not only simple varibles click the link at the bottom of the answer

Comment: Android BLE Device can't be serialized

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because ActB's onCreate() method is calling super(), it causes calling ActA's onCreate() method again and again. So, it's better not to extend ActA in ActB.
You can pass these values through passed  intent from ActA to ActB.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to brush up your OOP concepts.

As you have said **ActA** is more like a `SplashScreen`, so I assume **ActB** is the `MainScreen`. You should not `extend` **ActA** to create **ActB**. There is no `Is-A` relationship between them.

> Here's the problem: **ActB** extends **ActA** because it needs **ActA**'s retrieved data to perform it's tasks.

You have extended **ActA** for the very wrong reason.

Going forward, I assume (as you haven't provided any code) that you have written the code which starts **ActB** in **ActA**'s `onCreate()` method, that's why the issue

> This creates a loop because **ActA** starts retrieving other data and calls again **ActB**. So my app crashes.

*please note, due to your structure, once **ActB** is launched for the first time, it is the one which is retrieving the data and invoking itself* and not **ActA**.

please remove the inheritance and use `Intent.putExtra(key, value)` methods [(docs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) for passing the data from **ActA** to **ActB**.

e.g. in **ActA** after retrieving `some_data`

```
Intent i = new Intent(ActA.this, ActB.class);
i.putExtra("some_key", some_data);
ActA.this.startActivity(i);
```

and in **ActB** where the data is needed

```
Intent i = getIntent();
```

and retrieve the `some_data` from `i` using appropriate API `Intent.get<TYPE>Extra()`e.g. `i.getIntExtra("some_key")` [(docs)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int))

It will work.

Please refer @Malik's answer also.